# Group and stacked bar chart in apex charts react js

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I have created a horizontal bar stacked chart using apexcharts but I'm stuck at one and the last phase of completion and I tried so hard but were unable to find the solution, I've attached the actual chart and expected as well, all I want is just to group bars and show bars title.

series and options:

```
const series = [
    {
        name: 'Order Date',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-30'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-23'] },
            { x: '8PT-1', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-30'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-2', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-23'] },
            { x: '8PT-2', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-30'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-23'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-30'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-2', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-23'] },
            { x: '45PT-2', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-30'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-BBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'EM3VJOFPPF', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-25'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-CCC', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-DDD', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'RA7PSYODY6', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-25'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8LSBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-15'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-15'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45LSDD', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-15'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45LSDD', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45XDD', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-15'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XDD', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XBB', y: ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-20'] },
        ],
    },

    {
        name: 'Order Date Delay',
        data: [{ x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-6-30'] }],
    },

    {
        name: 'Approval Drawings',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-6-30', '2021-7-21'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-6-23', '2021-7-15'] },
            { x: '8PT-1', y: ['2021-6-30', '2021-7-21'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-2', y: ['2021-6-23', '2021-7-15'] },
            { x: '8PT-2', y: ['2021-6-30', '2021-7-21'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-6-23', '2021-7-15'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-6-30', '2021-7-21'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-2', y: ['2021-6-23', '2021-7-15'] },
            { x: '45PT-2', y: ['2021-6-30', '2021-7-21'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-BBB', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: '7RV3BTUV2E', y: ['2021-6-25', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-CCC', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-DDD', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'C5B4JOLXM5', y: ['2021-6-25', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8LSBB', y: ['2021-6-15', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-6-15', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45LSDD', y: ['2021-6-15', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45LSDD', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45XDD', y: ['2021-6-15', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XDD', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XBB', y: ['2021-6-20', '2021-7-18'] },
        ],
    },

    {
        name: 'Approval Drawings Delay',
        data: [{ x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-7-8', '2021-7-15'] }],
    },
    {
        name: 'Release For Manufacture',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-7-21', '2021-11-1'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-7-15', '2021-9-30'] },
            { x: '8PT-1', y: ['2021-7-21', '2021-10-15'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-2', y: ['2021-7-15', '2021-9-30'] },
            { x: '8PT-2', y: ['2021-7-21', '2021-10-15'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-7-15', '2021-9-30'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-7-21', '2021-10-15'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-2', y: ['2021-7-15', '2021-9-30'] },
            { x: '45PT-2', y: ['2021-7-21', '2021-10-15'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-BBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-CCC', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-DDD', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8LSBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-8-31'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-8-31'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45LSDD', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-8-31'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45LSDD', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45XDD', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-8-31'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XDD', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XBB', y: ['2021-7-18', '2021-10-1'] },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Release For Manufacture Delay',
        data: [
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-8-18', '2021-9-30'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-8-21', '2021-10-15'] },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Test Date',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-11-1', '2021-11-4'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-9-30', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: '8PT-1', y: ['2021-10-15', '2021-10-18'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-2', y: ['2021-9-30', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: '8PT-2', y: ['2021-10-15', '2021-10-18'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-9-30', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-10-15', '2021-10-18'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-2', y: ['2021-9-30', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: '45PT-2', y: ['2021-10-15', '2021-10-18'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-BBB', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-CCC', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-DDD', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8LSBB', y: ['2021-8-31', '2021-9-4'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-8-31', '2021-9-4'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45LSDD', y: ['2021-8-31', '2021-9-4'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45LSDD', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45XDD', y: ['2021-8-31', '2021-9-4'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XDD', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XBB', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-5'] },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Test Date Delay',
        data: [{ x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-10-2', '2021-10-5'] }],
    },

    {
        name: 'Ship Date',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWGR-MVA', y: ['2021-11-4', '2021-11-9'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-1', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-9'] },
            { x: '8PT-1', y: ['2021-10-18', '2021-10-20'] },
            { x: 'HV-8PT-2', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-9'] },
            { x: '8PT-2', y: ['2021-10-18', '2021-10-20'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-1', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-9'] },
            { x: '45PT-1', y: ['2021-10-18', '2021-10-20'] },
            { x: 'HV-45PT-2', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-9'] },
            { x: '45PT-2', y: ['2021-10-18', '2021-10-20'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-BBB', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: '2H30E81WAN', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-CCC', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-DDD', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: '742INZHY93', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8LSBB', y: ['2021-9-4', '2021-9-8'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-9-4', '2021-9-8'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8XBB', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45LSDD', y: ['2021-9-4', '2021-9-8'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45LSDD', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'ATS-45XDD', y: ['2021-9-4', '2021-9-8'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XDD', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-45XBB', y: ['2021-10-5', '2021-10-10'] },
        ],
    },

    {
        name: 'Ship Date Delay',
        data: [
            { x: 'SWBD-AAA', y: ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'SWBD-8LSBB', y: ['2021-10-2', '2021-10-10'] },
            { x: 'ATS-8XBB', y: ['2021-9-3', '2021-9-8'] },
        ],
    },
];

const options = {
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '63%',
            rangeBarGroupRows: true,
        },
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        enabledOnSeries: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
        formatter: function (val) {
            var a = moment(val[0]);
            var b = moment(val[1]);
            var diff = b.diff(a, 'days');
            return '+' + diff; //+ (diff > 1 ? ' days' : ' day')
        },
        textAnchor: 'middle',
        distributed: false,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ['#ffffff'],
        },
        dropShadow: {
            enabled: false,
            top: 1,
            left: 1,
            blur: 1,
            color: '#000',
            opacity: 0.45,
        },
    },
    colors: [
        '#008FFB',
        '#0065b3',
        '#00E396',
        '#00b377',
    ],
    fill: {
        type: 'gradient',
        gradient: {
            shade: 'light',
            type: 'diagonal',
            shadeIntensity: 0.01,
            gradientToColors: undefined,
            inverseColors: false,
            opacityFrom: 0.7,
            opacityTo: 0.9,
        },
    },
    dropShadow: {
        enabled: true,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        blur: 2,
        opacity: 0.5,
    },
    grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: '#DEE2E6', //'#90A4AE'
        strokeDashArray: 0,
        position: 'back',
        xaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: false,
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
            },
        },
        row: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.1,
        },
        column: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.1,
        },
        padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: undefined,
        labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: -45,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
            },
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            format: undefined,
            formatter: undefined,
            datetimeUTC: true,
            datetimeFormatter: {
                year: 'yyyy',
                month: "MMM 'yy",
                day: 'dd MMM',
                hour: 'HH:mm',
            },
        },
        lines: {
            show: true,
        },
        axisTicks: {
            show: true,
            borderType: 'solid',
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 6,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
        },
        axisBorder: {
            show: true,
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 1,
            width: '100%',
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
        },
        crosshairs: {
            show: true,
            width: 1,
            position: 'back',
            opacity: 0.9,
            stroke: {
                color: '#b6b6b6',
                width: 0,
                dashArray: 0,
            },
            fill: {
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#B1B9C4',
                gradient: {
                    colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                    colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                    stops: [0, 100],
                    opacityFrom: 0.4,
                    opacityTo: 0.5,
                },
            },
            dropShadow: {
                enabled: false,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                blur: 1,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: undefined,
            offsetY: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: 0,
                fontFamily: 0,
            },
        },
    },
    yaxis: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
        },
        labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: 0,
            rotateAlways: false,
            hideOverlappingLabels: true,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: undefined,
            maxHeight: 120,
            style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
            },
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            format: undefined,
            formatter: undefined,
            datetimeUTC: true,
            datetimeFormatter: {
                year: 'yyyy',
                month: "MMM 'yy",
                day: 'dd MMM',
                hour: 'HH:mm',
            },
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Equipment Tags',
            rotate: -90,
            offsetX: -1,
            offsetY: 0,
            style: {
                color: undefined,
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 600,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-title',
            },
        },
        axisTicks: {
            show: true,
            borderType: 'solid',
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 6,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
        },
        axisBorder: {
            show: true,
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 1,
            width: '100%',
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
        },
        crosshairs: {
            show: true,
            width: 1,
            position: 'back',
            opacity: 0.9,
            stroke: {
                color: '#b6b6b6',
                width: 0,
                dashArray: 0,
            },
            fill: {
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#B1B9C4',
                gradient: {
                    colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                    colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                    stops: [0, 100],
                    opacityFrom: 0.4,
                    opacityTo: 0.5,
                },
            },
            dropShadow: {
                enabled: false,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                blur: 1,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
        },
    },
    annotations: {
        xaxis: [
            {
                x: new Date('15 Sep 2021').getTime(), //new Date().getTime()
                borderColor: '#999',
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    text: "Today's Date",
                    style: {
                        color: '#fff',
                        background: '#775DD0',
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    chart: {
        background: '#fff',
        foreColor: '#373d3f',
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        showForSingleSeries: false,
        showForNullSeries: true,
        showForZeroSeries: true,
        position: 'right',
        horizontalAlign: 'left',
        floating: false,
        fontSize: '13px',
        fontWeight: 400,
        formatter: undefined,
        inverseOrder: false,
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined,
        tooltipHoverFormatter: undefined,
        customLegendItems: [],
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        labels: {
            colors: undefined,
            useSeriesColors: false,
        },
        markers: {
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            strokeColor: '#fff',
            fillColors: undefined,
            radius: 12,
            customHTML: undefined,
            onClick: undefined,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
        },
        itemMargin: {
            horizontal: 20,
            vertical: 4,
        },
        onItemClick: {
            toggleDataSeries: true,
        },
        onItemHover: {
            highlightDataSeries: true,
        },
    },
};
```

current output:

[image]

What I want:

```
          Actual:   -----------------------------         
SWGR-MVA
          Original: -----------------------------
```

Expected output image just to get a clear idea of what I want:

[image]